# How to match a column with a column that contains some blank cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Match Column F (Sheet 2)

[image]

with Column A (Sheet 1).

[image]

So as to get records as

[image]

I've a VBA method as -

```
Sub matchAndSortSort()
    Dim st As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Long

    Set st = Sheets("Sheet4")

    rw = st.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 2 To rw
        st.Cells(i, 125).Value = "=MATCH(F" & i & ",$A$2:$A$" & rw & ",0)"
    Next

    Range("F2:V" & rw).Sort Key1:=Range("G2:V" & rw), Order1:=xlAscending
    Range("H2:H" & rw).Clear

    Set st = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is giving me matching output but not considering blank cells.

How could I skip blank cell & put all the matching row values exactly in front of column A values?

Comment: Have you considered a `vlookup`?